# Change date format SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sep-19 (MONTH-YEAR) - varchar

String and what I need to do is change that to:

September 30, 2019 (MONTH DAY(LAST DAY OF THE MONTH),YEAR) varchar

I am working with SQL server 2014.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, you shouldn't be storing or accepting dates in this format.

But given that you already are, and undoubtedly the response will be that you can't fix it, you can use style 6 (`dd MMM yy`) and some string manipulation to revert this format back to a proper date. But you have to make sure your language settings match the way the data is stored:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english;

DECLARE @my char(6) = 'Sep-19';

SELECT EOMONTH(CONVERT(date, REPLACE('01 '+@my,'-',' '), 6));
```

I'm really not a big fan of `EOMONTH()` as this is about the only useful application of it. In my own code I would probably use something like this, even though it's more verbose:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CONVERT(date, REPLACE('01 '+@my,'-',' '), 6)));
```

Comment: I know that I shouldn't but the reality is that the excel files that I get from different areas in the company have multiple date format

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select eomonth(cast('01-' + month_year as date))
```

I'm not a fan of 2 digit years, but this should work for many examples of years.

Comment: Missing a `-`, since `'01' + month_year` results in value `01Sep-19`, and that gives error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` --- With dash, the result is `2019-09-30`

Comment: Ah yes, adding `'01-'` instead of '01' will work (but again only if the language is English).

Answer (score 1):

There are already qite a few good answers, but I'd like to add mine anyway:

```
declare @input as nvarchar(100) = 'Sep-19'

select FORMAT(EOMONTH(PARSE(LEFT(@input, 3) + '-01-' + RIGHT(@input, 2) as datetime using 'En-Us')), 'MMMM dd, yyyy')
```

The output is: "September 30, 2019"